# Update a div with results of a jqModal ajax call from MVC page

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-2, jqmodal

Here's my scenario.

I call jqModal using its ajax functionality that displays a form in the modal dialog. The user fills out some information and submits the form which returns some html in response.

The resulting html is being displayed inside the jqModal div. The user then clicks Close to dismiss the modal dialog.

This all works correctly so far.

Instead, what I want to do is close the dialog on submit and update a div with the response from the server.

Calling code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#jqmWindowContainer').jqm({
            modal: true,
            ajax: '.... url to display my form ...',
            onHide: myAddClose,
            ajaxText: 'Loading',
            toTop: true,
        });

        function myAddClose(hash) {
            hash.w.fadeOut('300', function () { hash.o.remove(); });
        }

    }); 

</script>
```

Calling page's markup. Clicking "Save this search" triggers the dialog.

```
    <a href="#" class="jqModal">Save this search</a>  
    <span id="jqmWindowContainer" class="jqmWindow"></span>
```

Form that is displayed:

```
   <div class="jqmPopupForm" id="jqmPopupForm">  
        <div id="loadingMessage" style="display: none;">
            Saving...
        </div>

        <% using (Ajax.BeginForm("Save", "AssetSearch", 
             new AjaxOptions() 
                 { HttpMethod = "Post", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                   UpdateTargetId = "jqmPopupForm", 
                   LoadingElementId = "loadingMessage"
                 }))
            {%>

            .... some html input elements go here ...

                <input type="submit" value="Save Search" />

                <a class="jqmClose" href="#">Cancel</a>                      

        <%
            }%>
    </div>
```

Right now, the entire jqmPopupForm div is being replaced by the results of the form submit.

How can I close the dialog and update a div on the page instead of making the user dismiss the dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can close the modal window by adding an `onSubmit` attribute to the form with the value `$('#jqmWindowContainer').jqmHide();`.  That should allow for the submission of the form while closing the modal.

UPDATE:

In the `ajaxOptions` portion of your ASP code, add the property `onSuccess` and specify a function that closes the modal window.

```
    <% using (Ajax.BeginForm("Save", "AssetSearch", 
         new AjaxOptions() 
             { HttpMethod = "Post", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
               UpdateTargetId = "jqmPopupForm", 
               LoadingElementId = "loadingMessage",
               OnComplete = "validateForm"
               OnSuccess = "closeWindow"
             }))
        {%>
```

where `closeWindow` is the name of the JavaScript function which will close the modal window, and
`validateForm` is the name of the JavaScript function which will validate the form before submission.

References:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460243.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.aspx

Comment: The Ajax.BeginForm adds its own onSubmit code. Are you suggesting that I can add additional onSubmit actions to the modal dialog form? Also, the dialog cannot be hidden if the server side validation fails.

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer. However, if the server side validation code fails, the sucess function is still called. This means that the dialog is dismissed even in the case of an error. How do I tell an error case from a normal case?

Comment: In this case, you need to provide the exact same validation client side using the `OnComplete` property and specifying a function that will validate the code (see update above).  It is good practice to provide client side validation and have server side validation only as a fallback.